# How to access JavaScript/jQuery function inside of Colorbox? I haven't got the satisfactory answer yet

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, colorbox

I'm using PHP, jQuery/JavaScript, Colorbox - a jQuery lightbox plugin, Smarty, etc. for my website. Now I'm displaying data in a popup using Colorbox plugin. The screenshot of popup is attached. In this popup there are several checkboxes. On the **OnChange event** of these checkboxes I'm calling the Javascript function, but it's not getting called. I did lot of research on this and come to know about the **"Colorbox's onComplete callback"**. I tried this but still it's not calling the JavaScript function. The popup is created using AJAX and jQuery. The code to generate the popup is as follows(this code gets executed upon onChange event of Checkbox):

```
function get_subject_topics(sheet_type, subject_id, sheet_id) { 

    var field_id = sheet_type+'_subject_'+subject_id;   
    var chk = document.getElementById(field_id).checked;

    if($.active > 0) { 
    request_inprogress(); 
    $('#'+chk).attr('checked', false);
    $('#topics_'+subject_id).remove();   
    } else {

      if(chk==true) {
        if(sheet_type=='practice') {
         GetSubjectTopicsForPracticeSheet(sheet_type, subject_id, sheet_id);
         $("#view_"+subject_id).show(1000);
       } 
    } else {
      remove_request('#practice_sheet_loader');
      $('#topics_'+subject_id).remove();
      $("#view_"+subject_id).hide(1000); 
    }
    }
}
```

The AJAX function(named GetSubjectTopicsForPracticeSheet()) which is responsible for displaying the data in Colorbox popup is as follows:

```
function GetSubjectTopicsForPracticeSheet(sheet_type, subject_id, practice_sheet_id) {
  $.colorbox({});
  $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: "practice_sheet.php",
    data: {'request_type':'ajax', 'op':'get_subject_topics_list', 'subject_id':subject_id, 'sheet_type':sheet_type, 'practice_sheet_id':practice_sheet_id},  
    success: function(data) {
        remove_request('#practice_sheet_loader');
        $('#subjects_topics_container').append(data);
        $.colorbox({inline:true, href:'#topics_'+subject_id, width:'80%'});

        $('.mini').prop("disabled", true);
        /*$.colorbox({onComplete:function(){
    alert("Hello");
}});*/


    }
  });

}
```

Now I want to call the following JavaScript function upon **OnChange event** of the checkboxes created inside the Colorbox popup, but I'm not able to give call to this function.

```
function enable_topic_ques(sheet_type, subject_id, topic_id) { 

    var field_id = sheet_type+'_'+subject_id+'_'+topic_id;  
    var chk = document.getElementById(field_id).checked;
    //alert(chk);

    if(chk==true) {
        if(sheet_type=='practice') {
          $('#'+sheet_type+'_'+subject_id+'_'+topic_id+'_'+1).removeAttr("disabled");
          $('#'+sheet_type+'_'+subject_id+'_'+topic_id+'_'+2).removeAttr("disabled");
          $('#'+sheet_type+'_'+subject_id+'_'+topic_id+'_'+3).removeAttr("disabled");
        } 
    }
    else {
        if(sheet_type=='practice') { $('#someid').attr('name', 'value');
          $('#'+sheet_type+'_'+subject_id+'_'+topic_id+'_'+1).attr('disabled', 'true');
          $('#'+sheet_type+'_'+subject_id+'_'+topic_id+'_'+2).attr('disabled', 'true');
          $('#'+sheet_type+'_'+subject_id+'_'+topic_id+'_'+3).attr('disabled', 'true');
        } 
    }  
}
```

Lastly the code from the smarty template to call the above function is as below:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-check" name="{$sheet_type}_topics_{$subject_topic_data.subject_id}[]" id="{$sheet_type}_{$subject_topic_data.subject_id}_{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}" value="{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}" onChange="enable_topic_ques('{$sheet_type}', '{$subject_topic_data.subject_id}', '{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}'); return false;">
```

Also there are no errors shown in the console of firebug. Can you help me in calling the Javascript function(named function enable_topic_ques()) on the **OnChange event** of the checkbox from Colorbox popup? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

the colorbox website :http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/
there are some Public Methods  maybe $.colorbox.element() is suit you, you can assign it to the parent js code , then you can deal with it.

or  maybe use Callbacks onLoad API to call enable_topic_ques() function

i test it; code is behind, but your code about checkbox change see works well, maybe your code is other position case problem;

add a slice html

```
<input type="submit" class="test-button">
```

add a js function test your code

```
function enable_topic_ques(sheet_type, subject_id, topic_id) {

                        // this is my add, it see it works normal
            alert('test');
            var field_id = sheet_type+'_'+subject_id+'_'+topic_id;  
            var chk = document.getElementById(field_id).checked;
            //alert(chk);

            if(chk==true) {
                if(sheet_type=='practice') {
                  $('#'+sheet_type+'_'+subject_id+'_'+topic_id+'_'+1).removeAttr("disabled");
                  $('#'+sheet_type+'_'+subject_id+'_'+topic_id+'_'+2).removeAttr("disabled");
                  $('#'+sheet_type+'_'+subject_id+'_'+topic_id+'_'+3).removeAttr("disabled");
                } 
            }
            else {
                if(sheet_type=='practice') { $('#someid').attr('name', 'value');
                  $('#'+sheet_type+'_'+subject_id+'_'+topic_id+'_'+1).attr('disabled', 'true');
                  $('#'+sheet_type+'_'+subject_id+'_'+topic_id+'_'+2).attr('disabled', 'true');
                  $('#'+sheet_type+'_'+subject_id+'_'+topic_id+'_'+3).attr('disabled', 'true');
                } 
            }  
        }

// this is my add

        $(".test-button").colorbox({inline:true, href:'.custom-check', width:'80%'});
```

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me:

```
$('#cboxLoadedContent iframe')[0].contentWindow.loadExit();
```

For example here is my index that calls colorbox:

This create the colobox and before closing it calls the function loadExit() function inside iframe.php

```
            $.colorbox({
                href:"iframe.php",
                onCleanup:function(){
                    $('#cboxLoadedContent iframe')[0].contentWindow.loadExit();
                }
            });
```

Hope it helps, 
yours Diogo